# Get weekly check in in a month through Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

In Javascript, how do I get the number of check ins weeks in a month? I can't seem to find code for this anywhere.

To be more specific, I would like to get the total number of user check-ins per week, that is, if during the week from 10/29/23 to 11/04/23 the user made 1 check-in or 4 check-ins, for example (a week being defined as starting on Sunday and ending on Saturday).

For example an user can only check in 3 times per 7 day period, but in "broken" weeks how is it possible to check if the user has already checked in 3 times? For example: Tom checks in on 10/30, 10/31 and 11/1. The system records the first two check ins, the third check in already corresponds to the month of November and is not being registered as a check in of the current week which is from 10/29 to 11/04.

If the user Tom wants to check in more than three times over a period of 7 days, the system must stop. However, as can be seen in the prompt image, check in on 11/01 does not appear as registered.

```
S  M  T  W  R  F  S
         1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8  9  10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30 31
```

When the user checks in on the first two days of the week it is registered, but when the month changes it is as if he had not checked in at all that week, how can I solve this?

```
const checkInOnWeek = await this.checkInsRepository.findByPlayerIdOnWeek(
      player_id,
      check_in_date,
    );

    const week = [];
    const current = new Date();
    // Starting Sunday not Monday
    current.setDate(current.getDate() - current.getDay());
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      week.push(new Date(current));
      current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1);
    }

    const datascheckin = week.map(date => {
      const firstdayFormatted = format(date, 'dd/MM');

      return firstdayFormatted;
    });

    const dataFormatada = format(check_in_date, 'dd/MM');

    const a = datascheckin.some(data => {
      return data === dataFormatada;
    });

    if (checkInOnWeek.length > 3) {
      console.log(
        `Qtd de checkins semanal atingida,
        ${checkInOnWeek[0].check_in_date}, Id ${checkInOnWeek[1].player_id}`,
      );
      throw new AppError('Weekly scheduling limit reached!', 400);
    }


    const countCheckInDate = await this.checkInsRepository.countSpacesRemaining(
      check_in_date,
    );


     const checkIn = await this.checkInsRepository.create({
       player_id,
       check_in_date,
     });

     return checkIn;
```

Result obtained
[image]

Comment: Can you rephrase or clarify: "I would like the number of check in of user of a weeks that have at least one day in the week"

Comment: Your example "an user can only check in 3 times in a week.." is not a good one. Can you give us a specific example? Something like "Alice checks in on 9th, 11th and 13th..." Followed by the results you are getting Vs the results you want.

Comment: Is the rule 'max 3 check-ins per calendar week' or 'max 3 check-ins per 7 day period'?

Comment: Thank you for the observations. I corrected the sentences and I hope the problem in question is now clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try to get the number of days of the first and last day of the month to see if the week has the number of days of the previous month and the next month.Maybe you can think of a better way